# Dual boot windows 7 with RC and XP?

Tags: windows-7, installation, multi-boot

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 RC and Win XP. I want to install the RTM version on a new drive.

What will happen to my dual boot menu? Will it:

A) Show 3 boot options (XP, RC & RTM)?

B) Show 2 boot options (RTM & RC)?

In the end I want only RTM and XP in the boot menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't touch the RC version it should show A).

It would make more sense to just install RTM on the same partition as the RC, so that then It would delete the RC and create a new boot menu with XP and RTM.

Comment: I agree with @Elvispt. If in the end you only want the RTM and XP, just Delete the RC and install RTM on that partition..